# How to set Selected item value of Picker React native

Tags: react-native

** here is code first pushing value on picker dynamically *****

```
const refItem = [];
for (var i = 0; i < this.state.ref_val1.length, i < this.state.ref_val2.length; i++) {

  s = this.state.ref_val1[i];
  val = this.state.ref_val2[i];
  refItem.push(<Picker.Item key={i} value={val} label={s} />);
}
```

**** and then setting it to state... but its not working****

```
<Picker
      selectedValue={this.state.selectedVar}
      onValueChange={(itemValue) => (this.setState({ selectedVar: itemValue }))} >

      {refItem}

    </Picker>
```

Comment: I have a very similar problem.